# plugin development in blackberry for blackberry mail client..?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to add an extra menu item in the blackberry default mail client application..
is there any way to develop this like a plugin..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to develop this via a BlackBerry Java app - see the [ApplicationMenuItemRepository class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/menuitem/ApplicationMenuItemRepository.html).